# toDF() not getting supported

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, iterable

I am very new to Scala. I am trying to convert an `Iterable[dataSet[Row]]` to a dataframe. Its not working for me. Here is the code

```
def execute(spark: SparkSession,
          input: Iterable[Dataset[Row]],
          execParams: Map[String, String]): Dataset[Row] = {

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import sparkSession.implicits._

val jsonSeq = Seq(input)
val jsonRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(jsonSeq)
val jsonDF = jsonRDD.toDF()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can first convert to a `Dataset` and then convert to a `Dataframe`

```scala
def execute(spark: SparkSession,
          input: Iterable[Dataset[Row]],
          execParams: Map[String, String]): Dataset[Row] = {
    import spark.implicits._

    val jsonSeq = Seq(input)
    val jsonRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(jsonSeq)
    val jsonDF = spark.createDataset(jsonRDD).toDF()
}
```

If you don't like converting to a Dataset, you can specify the type of RDD:

```
val jsonRDD: RDD[Iterable[Dataset[Row]]] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(jsonSeq)
val jsonDF = spark.createDataFrame[Iterable[Dataset[Row]]](jsonRDD).toDF()
```